# Java-8 Pass multiple parameters of method into a stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Consider I have this method which take multiple parameters, and I want to make some simple calculation like **count**, **sum**, **average**, **min**, **max**, Take a look at this native example :

```
public static void calculate(int... param) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i : param) {
        sum += i;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

How can I pass this parameters `(int... param)` in a Java-8 Stream and make this calculation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to do multiple checks on these params and only use one stream have a look at [IntStream.summaryStatistics()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#summaryStatistics--)

This will allow you to do this

```
IntSummaryStatistics statistics = IntStream.of(param).summaryStatistics();

statistics.getAverage();
statistics.getMax();
statistics.getMin();
statistics.getSum();
statistics.getCount();
```

IntSummaryStatistics is a very useful class for getting multiple statistics out of a stream.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Array.stream` like this :

```
//pass your method parameters in stream like this 
Arrays.stream(param).sum();
//--------------^---------
```

Here are some simple calculations:

```
public static void calculate(int... param) {
    //calculate sum
    Arrays.stream(param).sum();

    //calculate average
    Arrays.stream(param).average().getAsDouble();

    //count number of paramettres
    Arrays.stream(param).count();

    //find maximum
    Arrays.stream(param).max();

    //find minimum
    Arrays.stream(param).min();

    //find the first element
    Arrays.stream(param).sorted().findFirst();
}
```

Comment: Upvote for your answer. Also possible:    IntStream.of(test).sum();

Comment: oh this is good @kamehl23 you can post it like an answer maybe this can help others

Comment: Have you looked at when you have an IntStream you can use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#summaryStatistics--, this will return an object which will give you the Sum, Average ect

Comment: Nice self-answer!

Answer (score 5):

Also possible: `IntStream.of(param).sum();`